# Como descargar un archivo pdf?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, itextsharp

espero me puedan ayudar con esto...
Desarrollo una aplicacion web con c# asp.net
Estoy tratando de descargar un archivo que construyo usando la libreria iTextSharp.

Con este método construyo mi archivo PDF devuelvo el documento creado para recuperarlo con el js.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public Document crearPDF(){

            try
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

                Document document = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                PdfWriter pdf = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);

                document.Open();
                document.Add(new Paragraph("Hola esta es una prurba"));
                document.Close();
                byte[] Result = ms.ToArray();
                return document;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

ya en el js recibo mi documento creado mediante el result y lo descargo.

```
function descargarpdf(result) {

    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(result);
    a.download = "documento.pdf";
    a.click();

}
```

El result de metodo anterior es llamado aqui

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al momento de abrir el archivo descargado parece que esta dañado o algo parecido.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: De donde viene `result`? puedes agregar el codigo que llama a `descargarpdf()`?

Comment: El result lo obtiene del metodo crearPDF().

Comment: No estoy seguro del formato que llega el contenido en `result`. Puedes revisar el resultado de `console.log(typeof(result))` colocandolo dentro de la funcion `descargarpdf()`? De todas maneras se espera codificacion base64, no URL encoded (dependiendo del tipo de dato hay distintas soluciones)

Comment: el console.log(typeof(result)) solo imprime en consola la palabra "object"

Comment: Esto ya lo habias planteado en una pregunta previa. Si antes no se devolvia un base64 porque cree que ahora enviando un array de bytes lo va hacer. Pones un pdf como `text/plain` crees que eso es correcto?

Comment: si quieres descargarlo tienes que volver a usar el `Blob` como en al otra pregunta que realizaste anteriormente

Comment: Intente realizar lo del Blob pero no funciono :( y no creo que sea lo correcto lo del arreglo de bytes, soy nuevo usando estos métodos :(